# Как создать иерархию с кастомным типом записи?

Tags: php, wordpress

У меня есть 2 страницы на сайте: фотографы и видеографы. На каждой из этих страниц должны выводиться превью записей с перечнем городов. И вот когда переходишь на саму запись города в хлебных крошках должно быть следующее - "Главная - Фотографы - Москва".
При этом так же на сайте есть блог.
Изначально думала для городов сделать произвольный тип записи, но не пойму как тогда указать, что они относятся к странице фотографы, например, что б хлебные крошки выводились как указала выше. Можно так же сделать категорию Фотографы и уже у нее записи выводить..но очень не хотелось мешать эти записи с записями блога.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, может есть еще варианты как бы это правильнее сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте 1 новый тип записи, а у него создайте таксономию в которой уже будут фотографы и видеографы. А превью выводить не на обычных страницах, а на архивах(archive-post-type.php). Тогда хлебные крошки будут указывать на архив терма фотографы и т.д.

Comment: страница архива это прекрасно, но мне надо что б у пользователя была возможность редактировать информацию на странице архива в админке, а насколько знаю такой возможности нет

Comment: Так добавьте такую возможность. Например ACF позволяет добавлять свои поля на страницу таксономии, да и по дефолту есть поле description, хоть оно и не слишком удобное.

Comment: Или можно закостылить и выводить на архиве контент через get_the_content() с указанием поста из которого нужно вытащить контент. Сам так не делал, но думаю должно сработать

Comment: Причем тут таксономия?не совсем понимаю. Я говорю про страницу архива. Одна общая страница архива, у нее выводятся кастомный тип записи, у которого есть таксономия. Мне надо каким-то образом редактировать именно саму страницу архива

Comment: Когда вы открываете страницу архива у вас открывается архив не определенного типа записи, а архив одного терма, например фотографы. Для этого терма есть в админке страница редактирования, где можно менять название, слаг и т.д. Туда можно добавить определенные поля, которые будут уникальными для каждого терма. И потом их просто выводить